# How insert a varchar ' / / ' as null on date column in PostgreSQL 9

Tags: postgresql

I have an empty temp table and want to insert data from another table, but the date column in `temp` has `date` type, and the column in `usomultiple` is a `varchar`.

If I try to convert using the `to_date()` function, I get an ERROR because thousands of cells were saved with `'  /  /    '` as empty value.

> ERROR:  the value «/ » is not valid «dd»

```
INSERT INTO temp (
      cd_id,
      ds_estado,
      dt_date)  
    SELECT  um.cd_uso, um.ds_estado,to_date(um.dt_dateIn, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
    FROM usomultiple um;
```

How I can set null instead of `'  /  /    '` and the correct value when the cell is poblated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TO_DATE(NULLIF(dt_dateIn, '//'), 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```